# Angular after login page not refreshed with newest info

Tags: angular, typescript

Im creating my first login in Angular. All works fine, user is logged in, and he is redirected to GiveDashboardComponent and on nav bar instead of "login" button - "logout" is displayed, and the same opposite when he logout. The problem is that those changes appear for me only if i manually refresh the page (thats how i know it works). Whats the right way how to do it in Angular, or did i choose some wrong approach in current code?

My loginComponent:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User = new User();
  errorMessage: string = '';

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    public sharedService: SharedService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.authService.currentUserValue?.id) {
      this.router.navigate(['/give-dashboard']);
    }
  }

  exit() {
    this.sharedService.showLoginComponent = false;
  }

  login() {
    this.authService.login(this.user).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/give-dashboard']);
      },
      (err) => {
        this.errorMessage = 'Username or password is incorrect.';
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Navigation bar component:

```
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn = false;
  user: User = new User();

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.loggedUser.subscribe((res) => {
      if (res) {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
      } else {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    });
  }
  showLogin() {
    this.sharedService.showLoginComponent = true;
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['']);
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

And the Dashboard component (i tried simply with navigating, but thats clearly not the way)

```
export class GiveDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/give-dashboard']);
  }
}
```

And authenticationService:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  public currentUser: Observable<User>;
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  private isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.userIsLoggedIn());
  public loggedUser = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    let storageUser;
    const storageUserAsStr = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    if (storageUserAsStr) {
      storageUser = JSON.parse(storageUserAsStr);
    }
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(storageUser);
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  login(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<User>(API_URL + '/sign-in', user).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        if (res) {
          // set session-user
          this.setSessionUser(res);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
        return res;
      })
    );
  }

  register(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<User>(API_URL + '/sign-up', user).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        if (res) {
          this.setSessionUser(res);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
        return res;
      })
    );
  }

  setSessionUser(user: User) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(new User());
    // this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }
  refreshToken(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      API_URL + '/refresh-token?token=' + this.currentUserValue?.refreshToken,
      {}
    );
  }

  userIsLoggedIn() {
    return !!localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue looks like that there is problem with changeDetection. I would go with an Observable and Subject from the RxJS library. This allows components to subscribe to changes and update accordingly. You can use a BehaviorSubject in your AuthenticationService to hold the current state of the user.

Example of autheticationService:

```
 export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User | null>;
  public currentUser$: Observable<User | null>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    let storageUser: User | null = null;
    const storageUserAsStr = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    if (storageUserAsStr) {
      storageUser = JSON.parse(storageUserAsStr);
    }
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(storageUser);
    this.currentUser$ = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  setSessionUser(user: User) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }
  // ... remaining code
}
```

And in your NavBarComponent, subscribe to the currentUser:

TS.component of NavBarComponent:

```
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.currentUser$.subscribe((user) => {
      this.isLoggedIn = !!user;
    });
  }

  // ... remaining code
}
```

In this approach, whenever the user's state changes (login or logout), AuthenticationService updates its currentUserSubject, which in turn emits the change to all of its subscribers.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, my apologies - i didn't post my authentication service. I added it, can you take a look? I tried to adjust it to your approach, but it gets more messy, because i already use Observable, but it doesn't work as i expected.

Comment: @Ilze i eddit my response to your authentication service. 

The currentUser$ observable emits a value every time the currentUserSubject changes. The NavBarComponent subscribes to this observable, and updates isLoggedIn every time a new user value is emitted.

Now, every time you log in or log out, the NavBarComponent will get the updated user value and change isLoggedIn accordingly. Because isLoggedIn is bound to your view, this will trigger Angular's change detection and update your view.

Answer (score 0):

for me I juste I just keep it very simple if this was my code I'll juste add this simple code
location.reload(); here =>

```
login() {
    this.authService.login(this.user).subscribe(
      (data) => {

// add it here and thank me later :)
        location.reload()
        this.router.navigate(['/give-dashboard']);
      },
      (err) => {
        this.errorMessage = 'Username or password is incorrect.';
        console.log(err);
      }




// and of course also here 

 ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.authService.currentUserValue?.id) {
 
location.reload()
      this.router.navigate(['/give-dashboard']);
    }
  }
```

hope this work for you